# Am I going about this UV Unwrap the wrong way? How can I Unwrap this complex rope

Tags: modeling, rendering, export, uv-image-editor, unreal-engine

So I’ve spent the best part of few days constructing this Jakung Model sail boat to use in my first game. I have modelled it in Blender and can get a relatively nice UV map of the boat itself but the Ropes and all the finer detail has been completely disorientated and looks terrible in Unreal.

Every face on the boat has the correct normals with blue faces, but I’m struggling to figure out the best way to unwrap the UV’s for the Rope. I have tried marking them as seams but that didn't work and also marking edges as hard or sharp and that didn’t help with the rope at all. Any help anyone can provide me would be great or advice on how other people prepare UV maps for complex parts of models for export to be used in Unreal. I have attached a few pictures to show the model and problem I’m dealing with. Thanks in advance to anyone that can assist! [image: Level of detail in the rope]

This is the Current UV smart Unwrap project that I have projected.
[![UV Smart Unwrap (0.2) bounds @ 66 degrees]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4SfQ.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4SfQ.png)

This is without any sharp lines, Seams or Hard edges marked. When I did mark seams and lines the projection I got was just a Box with unrecognisable tiny black dots that didn't represent any sort of shape from my object. So this is the basic unwrap so far and the results/problem on the other end. [image: Render in Unreal Engine]

In some places like along the outrigger the rope is shape and jagged and in other places it just simply isn't even there. I'm new to UV Mapping and most of the tutes I have found don't go into this level of detail for such small and intricate objects as rope. I was thinking to UV unwrap it with a cylinder projection and then add that to the normal UV unwrap but I'm not sure how to go about doing multiple different types of Unwraps. Should all my objects still be joined. Or should I Unwrap each piece individually then merge them or something like that? [image: Total View of Boat]

Comment: You're not typically using geometry, in UE, with the vertex density you are showing for your rope.  Instead, you will typically create a low poly version and then "bake" textures from the high poly to the low poly.  The game engine never sees the high poly.  Here, your game engine is not showing the same vertex density that Blender is, and it's impossible to say why without knowing more (maybe, something about Blender; maybe, something about UE import or settings; need file to help with former and this is wrong forum for the latter.)  But-- none of it has anything to do with UV.

Answer (score 0):

You were totally right Nathan it had nothing to do with the UV's or Normal Faces or any of it. I highlighted the ropes which luckily I had assigned as a separate group anyway, I limited dissolve, the selection to decrease the density and file size, then I simply had to uncheck Create nanite on upload and all of finer detail was preserved. Then I enabled nanite afterwards and it now looks great.